# making a list of longitude with interval of 1 degree

Tags: python

I would like to make a list of longitude like this:

```
['0','1E','2E','3E','4E',....,'179E','180','179W','178W',......,'1W','0']
```

and I can achieve this by :

```
['0'] + [str(i)+'E' for i in range(1,180)] + ['180'] + [str(i)+'W' for i in range(179,0,-1)] + ['0']
```

However, I would like to know is there any more clean method?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that, but I doubt it is more elegant:

```
[str(degree % 360) if degree == 0 or degree == 360 or degree == 180 else str(degree) + 'E' if degree < 180 else str(360 - degree) + 'W' for degree in range(361)]
```

I personally prefer this:

```
longitudes = []   # ['0','1E','2E','3E',...,'179E','180','179W',...,'1W','0']
for degree in range(361):
    if degree == 0 or degree == 360 or degree == 180:
        longitudes.append(str(degree % 360))
    elif degree < 180:
        longitudes.append(str(degree) + 'E')
    else:
        longitudes.append(str(360 - degree) + 'W')
```

It is more bulky, but it is clearly apparent to the casual reader, what this code is doing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd appreciate your suggestion.